# Html, javaScript window.open

Tags: javascript, html

У меня данной командой открывается окно при нажатии на кнопку
`window.open('http://localhost:3001/api/auth/', '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');`.
Как сделать так чтоб если это окно открыто , то при нажатии на кнопку это окно не открывается?

Comment: Очень важный вопрос. Открыто в браузере или если Вы на нём находитесь сейчас?

Comment: когда окно открыто в браузере

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тогда вот решение:

```js
var a = document.getElementById('button'),
  w;
a.onclick = function() {
  if (!w || w.closed) {
    w = window.open('http://localhost:3001/api/auth/', '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');
  } else {
    console.log('Окно уже открыто');
  }
  w.focus();
};
```

```html
<a id="button">Открыть окно</a>
```

Рабочий [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)